# How to handle damaged barcodes in ml kit barcode scanner

Tags: image, barcode-scanner, android-camerax, google-mlkit, image-scanner

Below is the code for the Image Analyser class which will detect camera frames. I only want to show the manual entry option (which will be triggered by the error callback) when user is not able to scan barcodes. In the current scenario even when he is not scanning, this error callback will be called as the analyze method will be called for each camera frame. How to make sure this error() method is only called when barcode is scanned and we get empty barcodes?.

```
`@SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
    val mediaImage = imageProxy.image
    if (mediaImage != null) {
        InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)
            .let { image ->
                scanner.process(image)
                    .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
                        if (barcodes.isNotEmpty()) {
                            for (barcode in barcodes) {
                                onResult(barcode.rawValue ?: "")
                            }
                        } else error()
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener {
                        Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "Use case binding failed $it")
                    }
                    .addOnCompleteListener {
                        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                            delay(delayForProcessingNextImage)
                            imageProxy.close()
                        }
                    }
            }
    } else {
        Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "Image is empty")
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: Can you clarify "he is not scanning"? Camera is still open while not pointing to a potential barcode? Maybe you can try option #enableAllPotentialBarcodes
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/barcode/BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder#public-barcodescanneroptions.builder-enableallpotentialbarcodes

Comment: Yes camera is still open while not pointing to a barcode. I have tried the option of enableAllPotentialBarcodes, but still same issue. Iam still getting the callback in the success listener even while iam not scanning a barcode and camera is open.

Answer (score 0):

"When user is not able to scan" --- sounds to me you should time out here. e.g. report error after unable to detect barcode for x seconds.

As for barcode scanning, an easier way is to use the `androidx.camera:camera-mlkit-vision` artifact. See: https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/CameraX-MLKit